# Fail git push into private repo after installing microsoft git-credential-manager, repository not found

Tags: git, git-credential-manager

I am relatively new to using github. Recently, I install git-credential-manager in my Linux machine in order to work with my company's AzureDevOps accounts. It works flawlessly with both the Azure and my share company account, I no longer need to enter password whenever I make git push/pull. But, when I tried to make changes to my own personal account (private), which I have not update in a month, it give me an error of repository not found.

I am not sure what other information I need to provide, but any suggestion, help, or point me to a direction will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like git-credential-manager stored your Azure account, and is using it to attempt to login to your personal github account.  Maybe try prefacing your personal github push URL with your username@github...?

Comment: it does seems to be what you suggest. I create a dummy repo in my private repo, and use 
    git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git 
it will clone the repo.